# Dropped all tables

Tags: laravel, database-migration

I am using one database for two separate projects.
Instead of *migrate:refresh* I used (stupid mistake) *migrate:fresh* and dropped all my tables from both projects.
Now I am not able to run *php artisan migrate* because I am missing the migrations from the first project. Locally, I have only the ones from the second project.
This is the full error:
[image]

How to resolve it?

Comment: I think that if you use a shared database with multiple projects, your should use migration files on a single project. Otherwise you won't be able to migrate a fresh database if the definition are splitted between the projects.

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier It was not my intention to run fresh. I wanted to run refresh, but I did a careless mistake.

Comment: An intention or not, no one will ever be able to mount the projects if the migration files are separated between multiple location (I guess it's make sense). I really think you should aggregate them into a single place. And by doing so, it may solve your issue